# Every separable Banach space embeds in $C[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

> Every separable Banach space is isometrically isomorphic to a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$.

I know the result that every Banach space is isometrically isomorphic to a closed subspace of $C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff $X$. This is proven using Alaoglu's theorem. However, I don't know how to improve this result, replacing $X$ by $[0,1]$.

Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: This is a whole theorem, known as the Banach-Mazur theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem

Comment: @pitariver Thanks! I've voted it to be duplicate.